# Embed file in excel worksheet/cell

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop, epplus

I hope someone can help me. Is there a way to embed a specific file (.txt) into an excel cell? I'm currently using epplus, and I would like to embed programmatically a file into a specific excel cell. I did manage to add a hyperlink, but my goal is to have it embedded.

Worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, colNumber].Value = ....

Is there any way to do it? I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: To be clear, you want to place the *entire contents* of `myFile.txt` in a single Cell in Excel, programmatically?  Or do you want to add the `.txt` file as an object, and double clicking it opens the file?

Comment: Should not be a problem. The contents of the text file is a string so you can read it and put it in a Cell.

Comment: I want to add the .txt file as an object and open it by double clicking. I don't want it as a link to that file, I want to embed it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can certainly put text within a cell, but bear in mind Excel does have a limit to the number of characters it will allow in a single cell.  It's pretty large, but conceivably the contents of a text file could exceed that limit -- even if future versions of Excel keep increasing what the limit is (as they have in the past).

You can also embed an OLE object in your worksheet, and a text file qualifies for that.  I don't know that you can assign it to a cell, per se.  You can change the location, shape and behavior to fit in a cell and behave as though it's part of a cell, but I don't know that it ever belongs to a range the way formulas do.  I could be wrong.

The basic construct of how to embed an OLE object into a worksheet is as follows:

```
Excel.OLEObject ole = ws.OLEObjects().Add(Filename: @"C:\Users\hambone\Documents\foo.txt");
```

This is the equivalent of the VBA:

```
Set ole = sh.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="C:\Users\hambone\Documents\foo.txt")
```

The method returns an `OLEObject` object, which you can then shape to behave the way you want:

```
ole.Height = 5;
```

Comment: I have tried to use OLEObjects, but I don't know how to implement it, as this is interop, and I used epplus only in my entire program.

Comment: Aah, your tags had interop, so I assumed that was an option on the table.  EPPlus is fantastic, but it does have functionality limitations, and you may have found one.  Interop has access to the VBA runtime library, so there isn't much it can't do.

Comment: It could be an option on the table. I tried to use it after saving on Excelpackage, but I had an error " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"